# vscode-python extension - "python.envFile"/"envFile" parameters doesn't work

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, environment-variables

I'm trying to configure a FastAPI based Python project to consume an .env (enviroment variables) file from an alternate location.

I've tried every possible configuration so that VSCode (vscode-python extension) loads the .env file from a specific location. Nothing works. I believe this is a bug of the vscode-python extension.

**Any ideas on how I can resolve this (a workaround is also acceptable)?**

settings.json (Workspace and User)

```
{
    [...]
    "python.envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env-DEV"
    [...]
}
```

launch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            [...]
            "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env-DEV",
            [...]
        }
    ]
}
```

**NOTE:** In the [.env file not working #9358](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/9358) thread it is not clear if this has been fixed or not. Apparently it's an old problem and hasn't been fixed.

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **python-dotenv** packages.

- Install **python-dotenv** using `pip install python-dotenv` command in terminal

  [image]
- File structure

  ```
  pyenv
  ├─ .env
  └─ Test.py
  ```
- Sample code

  ```py
  from dotenv import load_dotenv
  import os
  load_dotenv()
  print(os.environ.get("envvar"))
  ```
- Operation result

  [image]

**Note:** If the env file name is not **`.env`**. Then you need to specify the file path in the code.

[image]

---

**EDIT**

*launch.json* configuration available in debug case

[image]

Comment: I believe **the presence of these parameters** is what made the scheme in the last image work, as otherwise that's exactly what I was doing... `"console": "integratedTerminal",` and `"justMyCode": true,`

Comment: By the way, awesome answer! 